# Lightroom having problems importing old PSD files

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, software, photo-management

I recently installed the newest Adobe Lightroom Classic. I tried to import an old PSD file created by Photoshop CS5. Lightroom does not succeed in importing it. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you read this PSD in any other program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a layered psd file without the composite (flattened version) embedded, which LR cannot use.

If you open the file in Photoshop and resave it with "maximize compatibility" enabled it will add the composite and LR should be able to import it.

Lightroom doesn't actually work with layered files (psd/tiff)... it works with the embedded flattened image.

Edit to add:
If you put them all in a folder you can use PS to run a script to convert them all at once.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to batch-convert PSD files to compatible PSD files using Adobe Bridge CS5 and Adobe Photoshop CS5?

Comment: @Triceratops, it can be done with PS; I added a description and picture showing how. This is the current version (Beta actually), but I'm 99% certain it's the same in earlier versions.